# Transformation Scene

Tags: transformation, movement

Hello Everyone, I'm working on sound design for a shortfilm involving main character, who has 2 personalities, transform into his evil version, thru violent head-shaking movement. The actor make some noise while doing the scene, but I want to add some effects that could highten up the tension.   Need some suggestions.  What would u use? or What other famouse movies have used before?

Answer (score 4):

I'd argue that the biggest decision should be whether to go more literal and "cover" the physical transformation, or to be more metaphorical and express his emotional transformation. I've seen it done both ways; any werewolf movie since "An American Werewolf In London," and any number of other horror films, do the latter, and usually the ol' vegetable violence tricks pay off the best here. Going metaphorical, yeesh, could be anything, but your hands aren't tied to being literal anymore, and your choices can mesh better to the emotion of the character and/or even the key and timbres of the soundtrack, if any.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Jacob's Ladder](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099871/). Excellent use of sound to sell a very scary visual effect. There's a sample around 1:50 on [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SXXbIOc9h4g) YouTube video.

Comment: Indeed! Very freaky movie, great great soundtrack.

Answer (score 1):

wow...thank you so much, everyone. I wish I could upload the clip too, but that's up to the director. I will post once I'm done with it. Thank you for all your advice. I'll try and see which ways go well

Comment: Have fun experimenting!

Answer (score 0):

Dissect the transformation scene. If there are obvious physical changes like muscle contractions, fingernail elongation etc. , it is usually easy to cover it with some organic stretch, squash or pinching sounds.

If the viewers are seeing only before and after versions of transformation, than it is up to your imagination and any surreal sound design suitable to the needs of the scene would do the job.

From composing point of view I would suggest using [dim5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tritone) chords (diminished 5ths) This harmonic distortion supports "something bad" feelings of a particular scene.

With all due respect to:

[image]